# Coin Estimator by Weight

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, calculator

I've created a mini project where the user will enter the total weight of the coins and the program will compute how many coins they have and how many wrappers they'll need. I initially found this challenge in a subreddit named r/beginnerprojects

```
def coinEstimator():

    ##########################################
    # Intro text                        ######
    ##########################################

    print("Welcome to the coin estimator.")
    print("Please enter the type of coins: ")
    print("1. Cent")
    print("2. Nickel")
    print("3. Dime")
    print("4. Quarter")


    ##############################################
    # Setting up variables for the user's input ##
    ##############################################

    userChoose = int(input("Enter: "))


    ##############################################################
    # Conditionals for different types of coin the user wants.  ##
    ##############################################################

    if userChoose == 1:             # Conditionals for Cents
        totalWeight = float(input("What is the total weight of your cents in grams?\n"))

        (cointValue, dimeWrapper) = cointEstSol(totalWeight, "Cent")

        print("The total cents you have is {0}. You need {1} wrapper(s)".format(cointValue, dimeWrapper))

    elif userChoose == 2:           # Conditionals for Nickel
        totalWeight = float(input("What is the total weight of your nickels in grams?\n"))

        (cointValue, dimeWrapper) = cointEstSol(totalWeight, "Nickel")

        print("The total nickels you have is {0}. You need {1} wrapper(s)".format(cointValue, dimeWrapper))

    elif userChoose == 3:           # Conditionals for Dime
        totalWeight = float(input("What is the total weight of your dimes in grams?\n"))

        (cointValue, dimeWrapper) = cointEstSol(totalWeight, "Dime")

        print("The total dimes you have is {0}. You need {1} wrapper(s)".format(cointValue, dimeWrapper))

    elif userChoose == 4:           # Conditionals for Quarter
        totalWeight = float(input("What is the total weight of your quarters in grams?\n"))

        (cointValue, dimeWrapper) = cointEstSol(totalWeight, "Quarter")

        print("The total quarters you have is {0}. You need {1} wrapper(s)".format(cointValue, dimeWrapper))


def cointEstSol(weight, coins):

    ########################################################
    ## Setting up variables for the solution of coins    ###
    ########################################################

    coinWeight = {"Cent": 126, "Nickel": 199, "Dime": 113, "Quarter": 226}     # Dictionary for the different weights of coins
    coinCountWrap = {"Cent": 50, "Nickel": 40, "Dime": 50, "Quarter": 40}      # Dictionary for the amount of coins that can be put in a wrapper

    cointValue = weight // coinWeight[coins]                                   # Solution to compute how many coins we have

    if cointValue < coinCountWrap[coins]:                                      # Conditionals for how many wrappers would be needed.
        coinWrapper = 1
    else:
        coinWrapper = cointValue // 50
        coinWrapper += 1

    return (cointValue, coinWrapper)                                           # Returning the total amount of coins and wrapper

coinEstimator()
```

Please tell me what areas i need to improve. As you can see my code is crude and was not beautifully written.

Honest review would be needed. Any shortcuts, codes that need amendments or just a way to improve this code would be appreciated.

Extra inquiry:
Although i don't think this would be the appropriate place to ask this questions but i want this to be made as object oriented programming approach. I don't know how, so if you guys can convert this code to OOP, that would be great. I wanted to know how python experts would approach this in an OOP style. It's okay if you don't answer this.

Answer (score 2):

You got the right approach by using dictionaries and helper function (`coinEstSol`). You should go further and provide the same kind of approach to `coinEstimator`.

Furthermore, having informations split in several collections, such as your `coinWeight` and `coinCountWrap` is not ideal as it gets harder to extend them latter. Instead, you could work with triplets reprensenting a coin: name, weight and wrap. You could also use `collections.namedtuple` to make for better understanding of what these values are.

I would use a list to store these coin informations as it allows for automatic building of the menu:

```
import collections


Coin = collections.namedtuple('Coin', 'name weight wrap')


COINS = [
    Coin('Cent', 126, 50),
    Coin('Nickel', 199, 40),
    Coin('Dime', 113, 50),
    Coin('Quarter', 226, 40),
]


def estimate(coin):
     question = 'What is the total weight of your {}s in grams?\n'.format(coin.name)
     weight = float(input(question))
     value = weight // coin.weight
     wrapper = value // coin.wrap
     if value % coin.wrap:
         wrapper += 1
     return coin.name, value, wrapper


def main():
    print("Welcome to the coin estimator.")
    print("Please enter the type of coins: ")
    for index, coin in enumerate(COINS, 1):
        print(index, coin.name)

    user_choice = int(input('Enter: '))
    name, value, wrapper = estimate(COINS[user_choice - 1])
    print('The total', name, 'you have is', value, 'You need', wrapper, 'wrapper(s)')
```

Be aware, also, that your `float` and `int` calls can raise `ValueError` if the user doesn't enter a numeric value. You can also get an `IndexError` if the choice from the user is over the number of coins defined. Depending of your needs, you may want to take care of that.

Comment: I see, by using a triplets i could easily take care the management of the information. Wow your code looks beautiful. Its so clean. I 've learned alot. Thank you.